# XeLaTeX, WinEdt 6.0 and UTF-8

Tags: xetex, unicode, winedt

I'm using WinEdt 6.0 and need to write German umlaute. Using XeLaTeX, i need to save the tex-file in utf-8 to have native support for this - does anyone know how to tweak WinEdt so that it saves in utf-8?

Comment: I'm surprised that there are still editors that don't use utf8 by default.

Comment: Cough *notepad* cough...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Winedt can handle utf8 if you need only chars from one codepage (e.g. if you are only using the chars from ansinew). For a new document you can set the encoding in documents settings, tab format. If you need to convert documents: There is a utf-8.tex in winedt 6/Samples/examples that explains the details.

Comment: Thanks, the utf-8.tex was very helpful, now it works (at least for my purpose).

Answer (score 3):

UTF-8 is planned for WinEdt 6.1. It uses it's own text editor, not a library, and so UTF-8 support has to be written from the ground up. You can use other encodings which WinEdt can work with to use accents natively, or can use its build-in translation system.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you give me a pointer where I might find these workarounds?